# Retrieve the session (In List) using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to retrieve the session values which are stored in the list using javascript?

I used this code to set the session in the controller.

```
  List<test> _test= new List<test>();
  if (Session["testsession"] == null)                
            Session["testsession"] = _test;
```

I used this code to retrieve the session list values using javascript

```
  var TEST ='@HttpContext.Current.Session["quotesession"]';
```

but when i debug it the output is in

```
     var TEST ='System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NLG.IMS.Shared.Models.Test]';
```

Where i went wrong? I need the session values to be retrieved from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise using a strongly typed model and assigning a property to the collection rather than using session, even the `ViewBag` would be better but if you really must, this is how you could:

You could use the following:

```
var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@HttpContext.Current.Session["quotesession"]));
```

Which would output it as json.

[**jsFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4mew1C)

The above prints out a collection to the console.log.

Comment: Thank u. I also got the same result while using session also.

Comment: I need one more info. How to split those objects?

Comment: @AarthiRavendiran If you mean loop, I use `jQuery.each`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I dn't want to loop. i need to obtain specific values from that. What method should i need to use?

Comment: @AarthiRavendiran If it is a collection, you would access each property with either `.` notation or square brackets `[]` i.e. `json[0].Property1` or `json[0]["Property1"]` would access the first one. Obviously use the property in your object though.